# Scala concurrency on iterators as queues

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I'm not really sure of the correct language of my problem, so feel free to provide me with the right terms.

Say I have a process A, which outputs an iterator (lazy evaluation)
This produces Iterator[A]

I then have another process B, which maps the events returning
Iterator[B]

This continues for several more processes
Iterator[A] -> Iterator[B] -> Iterator[C] -> ---

Now eventually I evaluate this stream into a list[Z].
This saves me the memory hit of having a List[A] -> List[B] -> List[C] etc

Now I want to improve performance by introducing parallelisation, but I don't want to parallelise the evaluation of each element across the iterators, but rather each iterator stack.  So in this case a thread for process A fills a Queue[A] for Iterator[A], a thread for process B takes from Queue[A], applies whatever mapping, and then adds to Queue[B] for Iterator[B] to read from.

Now I have done this before in other languages by designing my own Async queues, I was wondering what Scala has to solve this.

Comment: One way is to make it with actors: e.g. actor B listens for message (item) from actor A, on receive processes item and sends it to C and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a first stab solutions I made using an actor.
Its fully blocking, so maybe an implementation using futures could be developed

```
case class AsyncIterator[T](iterator:Iterator[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
  private val queue = new scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedQueue[Int]()
  private var end = !iterator.hasNext

  def hasNext() = {
    if (end) false
    else if (!queue.isEmpty) true
    else hasNext
  }

  def next() = {
    while (q.isEmpty) {
      if (end) throw new Exception("blah")
    }
    q.dequeue()
  }

  private val producer: Actor = actor {
    loop {
      if (!iterator.hasNext) {
        end = true
        exit
      }
      else {
        q.enqueue(iterator.next)
      }
    }
  }
  producer.start()
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Since you're open to alternative languages, how about Go?

There was [a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810261/go-lang-closure-pipeline-deadlock) recently about how to construct an event-driven pipeline, which would achieve the same thing as you describe but in a completely different way.

It's arguably easier to think about and design an event pipeline than it is to reason about lazy iterators because it becomes a data flow system in which the key question at each stage is 'what does this stage do with a *single* entity?' rather than 'how can I *iterate efficiently* over many entities?'

Once an event-driven pipeline has been implemented, the question of how to make it concurrent or parallel is moot - you've already done it.

Comment: Now using just iterators, the process flow is driven from right to left.  The list building at the end drives the process.  Now if I understand this, the event pipeline would be driven from the left, so the first process would keep firing events telling the next process in the chain that an item is ready, the next process would handle each event as it was ready for them.  If the secondary process was faster it would wait for the event (futures maybe?), if slower, a queue of events will build up.  This correct?

Comment: Yes, it has built-in flow control. This is a useful advantage of this technique.

Also note that it is possible to use a similar 'pull-driven' design, like a daisy-chain of client-server relationships between stages. The last stage is the client of the previous stage - it would request a value and wait for the result. The previous stage is then a client of its predecessor etc, all the way back to the first stage. If judicious buffering is built in, this approach would be similar to the push approach in term of bubbling results through efficiently, but would seem more of a 'lazy' method.